# how to extract only Noun Phrases from a sentence using stanford nlp in java?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I got a tree format for a sentence(This is a Java Certification) using Stanford nlp in java as below

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (DT This))
    (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP (DT a) (NNP Java) (NNP Certification)))))
```

Now,my requirement is to extract only Noun phrases using Stanford nlp in java from the above tree format.Please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: How is this tree represented in memory? As objects containg their children? A a string?

Answer (score -1):

If I remember it correctly this structure is represented as list in memory. From there you can just drill down to the POS tags that interest you.